# Does LUKS disk encyption break SLC caching on QLC/TLC SSDs?

Tags: linux, luks, ssd, disk-encryption

It seems that modern SSDs degrade in performance the more data they are holding.
My understanding is that this is because manufacturers put less and less storage cells on the SSDs relative to their total capacity and now we reached a point where a single cell stores up to 4 bits (QLC) instead of just one, greatly reducing the performance.

One trick modern SSDs use is `SLC caching` which means that performance is increased by only storing 1 bit per cell. But with a QLC (4 bits per cell) SSDs, you can only do this until the SSD is 1/4 (25%) full and with TLC (3 bits per cell) that would be at 1/3 (33%).

This is just my poor understanding of the technology, I'm sure it's more complicated in reality, but I have seen countless reports of QLC SSDs dropping in performance once a certain threshold is reached.

The important question is, what happens if I use LUSK disk encryption on such an SSD? Will it think that is 100% full and thus not be able to use `SLC caching`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The important question is, what happens if I use LUSK disk encryption on such an SSD? Will it think that is 100% full

From the point of view of the disk there is no difference between LUKS and any other "non encryption" filesystem like Ext or XFS. Formatting a device to LUKS doesn't encrypt the entire device, only blocks of newly written data to the filesystem on top of the LUKS/dm-crypt device are encrypted and written to the disk.

Only think you should make sure to do with LUKS and SSD is to [allow the discard option](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)) in `/etc/crypttab` to make sure TRIM goes through the dm-crypt device to the disk.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was just thinking that maybe LUKS would fill the empty space with random data, to hide some meta data like how much encrypted data there is.

Comment: No, LUKS doesn't do that. The only situation where this happens is if you set the authenticated encryption (combination of LUKS and dm-integrity) with the `--integrity` option, but that isn't default.